# Why is my <Form action=home/Update> is getting automatically changed upon loading the page?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, forms

I have a problem with a form on visual studio using `ASP.NET`.

This is my form:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <form method="post" action="/update">
        <h4>Edit</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model[0].idContrato, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model[0].idContrato, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[0].idContrato, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div> ... <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

When I execute and inspect it, the line: `<form method="post" action="/update">` is changed into `<form action="/home/Edit/010001" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">` where `/home/Edit/010001` is the URL of my page and `010001` the id of the contract I want to edit in my form.

So when I press the button validate, it refreshes the page and nothing happens.

Any idea?

Comment: Is there php in this, or is it all c#?

Comment: What happens when you use Using(Html.BeginForm()){}?

Comment: @TankorSmash It's all c# at the moment.

Comment: @AnupSharma It's a code generated by Visual Studio and i don't really know what it is (I heard it was for security), but because you asked, i tried to delete it and now everything is working perfectly, do you have any idea why this property was doing that? I'm curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer was to delete the Using(Html.BeginForm()){}, but i'm still wondering why...